# JavaScript naming conventions

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I know there is a lot of controversy (maybe not controversy, but arguments at least) about which naming convention is the best for JavaScript.

How do you name your variables, functions, objects and such?

I’ll leave my own thoughts on this out, as I haven’t been doing JavaScript for long (a couple of years, only), and I just got a request to create a document with naming conventions to be used in our projects at work. So I’ve been looking (googling) around, and there are so many different opinions.

The books I’ve read on JavaScript also use different naming conventions themselves, but they all agree on one bit: “Find what suits you, and stick to it.” But now that I’ve read so much around, I found that I like some of the other methods a bit better than what I’m used to now.

Comment: An up-to-date guide to common sense Naming Conventions in JS: https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-naming-conventions

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I follow [Douglas Crockford's code conventions](https://www.crockford.com/code.html) for JavaScript.  I also use his [JSLint](https://www.jslint.com/) tool to validate following those conventions.

Comment: JSLint can be too radical and restrictive for many developers, then [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) can be better choice.

Comment: There is also the [Online Javascript Beautifier][1] (http://jsbeautifier.org) which seems to use all the Douglas Crockford conventions to format the code. It does not address the naming of variables and functions though. 


  [1]: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Crockford doesn't go into this level of detail, but what about variables that happen to start with a capital letter, because they refer to an acronym - should the first letter, or the entire acronym be lowercased? Example: `ECBhandle` vs. `ecbHandle` (it does _not_ matter what ECB means).

Comment: Although it's a good link, I can't believe a "link answer" has so many votes. You could at least extract & format the relevant parts of the linked page.

Comment: I think he is doing fine with the link. If you are so concerned you should edit the post.

Comment: I really look up to Crockford but his code conventions seem very outdated. I would advice looking at @PavelHodek  answer further down the list

Comment: This is not an answer. The document linked doesn't talk at all about naming conventions for variables, but for code in general.

Answer (score 161):

As Geoff says, what [Crockford says](http://crockford.com/javascript/code.html) is good.

The only exception I follow (and have seen widely used) is to use $varname to indicate a jQuery (or whatever library) object.  E.g.

`var footer = document.getElementById('footer');`

`var $footer = $('#footer');`

Comment: I use $ for this as well. I often see people use $ to indicate a cached copy of an object. I always assumed it was  play on words.
    cache > "cash" > $

Comment: This might not be the best idea if you're using AngularJS - core services are prefixed with '$'

Comment: I highly recommend NOT using special characters in variable names. A lot of frameworks use $ especially.

Comment: @nixxbb That's fine if you rightly scope variables - which decent frameworks do too.

Answer (score 117):

You can follow the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming).

In general, use functionNamesLikeThis ([lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)), variableNamesLikeThis, ClassNamesLikeThis ([upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)), EnumNamesLikeThis, methodNamesLikeThis, and SYMBOLIC_CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS.

See a nice collection of [JavaScript Style Guides And Beautifiers](https://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/).

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully agree with that, considering that they developed Dart and GWT (the chrome extensions javascript api is also very java-like).  To some teams in Google, the best way to develop javascript might be to write it in some other language.

Comment: I always found Google's private naming convention *odd*, instead of `_fooBar` they do `fooBar_` - Microsoft got it right: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_contribute_codingStandards.ashx

Comment: @DanielSokolowski What about when using intellisense? If you prefix a large number of variables with an underscore, then that's just another character you have to type every time you access those variables. With it at the end, your intellisense list looks cleaner and it's just a little bit quicker to find what you need.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer true about the extra character but I don't think its faster. Typing `_` when referencing private vars would result in intellisense right away limiting the results; in the end thought it's personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the list of style guides. I don't know if one is worth following exclusively or how to decide yet which one or whether I should use an amalgamation. But knowing where to find several in one place is a real boon.

Answer (score 10):

One convention I'd like to try out is naming static modules with a 'the' prefix. Check this out. When I use someone else's module, it's not easy to see how I'm supposed to use it. E.g.,

```
define(['Lightbox'],function(Lightbox) {
  var myLightbox = new Lightbox() // I am not sure whether this is a constructor (non-static) or not
  myLightbox.show('hello')
})
```

I'm thinking about trying a convention where static modules use 'the' to indicate their preexistence. Has anyone seen a better way than this? It would look like this:

```
define(['theLightbox'],function(theLightbox) {
  theLightbox.show('hello') // Since I recognize the 'the' convention, I know it's static
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that besides some syntax limitations; the naming conventions reasoning are very much language independent.  I mean, the arguments in favor of c_style_functions and JavaLikeCamelCase ([upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)) could equally well be used the opposite way; it's just that language users tend to follow the language authors.

Having said that, I think most libraries tend to roughly follow a simplification of Java's upper camel case.  I find [Douglas Crockford advice](http://javascript.crockford.com/style1.html) tasteful enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

That's an individual question that could depend on how you're working.

Some people like to put the variable type at the beginning of the variable, like "str_message". And some people like to use underscore between their words ("my_message") while others like to separate them with upper-case letters ("myMessage").

I'm often working with huge JavaScript libraries with other people, so functions and variables (except the private variables inside functions) got to start with the service's name to avoid conflicts, as "guestbook_message".

In short: English, lower-cased, well-organized variable and function names is preferable according to me. The names should describe their existence rather than being short.

Comment: "so functions and variables (except the private variables inside functions) got to start with the service's name to avoid conflicts," This statement is **inaccurate**. You can correctly have "namespaced" functions and objects that do not bleed through multiple javascript frameworks. There was a very good presentation on how to achieve this from MIX11 http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/OPN08

Comment: Re *"put the variable type at the beginning of the variable"*: That It is ***system*** Hungarian notation, not the real Hungarian notation. The Windows documentation team [messed it up](https://twit.tv/shows/triangulation/episodes/277)—at [04 min 00 secs](https://cdn.twit.tv/audio/tri/tri0277/tri0277.mp3) (even though the author explicitly warned against it). And now it is tainted.