# How do you name your classes when it comes to JavaScript vs CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some classes that are there for css, and there are some classes that are there for JavaScript.

What naming convention do you use to denote "look for this class in the JavaScript file(s)" as opposed to: "Look for this class in the css file(s)" as opposed to "Look for this class everywhere".

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to name them using noun modifiers, so adjectives, prepositional phrases, or sentences using the verbs "to have" minus the subject.  E.g.,

1. adjectival : `upToDate`, `stale`
2. prepositional : `fromSameUser`
3. verbal : `hasProblems`

Comment: So, then you use camelcase for both CSS and JS?

Comment: @Bryce, yes, but I have no rational argument as to why anyone else should do so.

Comment: Makes sense. Everyone should do it how they feel comfortable. I just like to see how others do it and pull ideas.

Comment: I'll try something like this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, I think what should happen is this

1. build the structure of the site in HTML
2. add styling with CSS (here's where the classes are added)
3. hook javascript via already created classes and IDs
4. add additional classes/IDs only where necessary.

In most cases this keeps it all wrapped together nicely.

If the scripting is done last (which I think is best), the structure should be there to support it.

So, in almost all cases your js classes/IDs would mirror your CSS stuff.

**EDIT**

To provide additional info as per @Bryce Siedschlaw's comment:

Most of my classes/IDs are based on the element's function.  Some examples of rules I created/modified today

```
#successExplain{}  
.successImgs{}
.continueRead{}
.continueRead a{}
.continueRead a:hover{}
#tagCloud{}
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't think you actually answered the question. You didn't actually mention how the CSS stuff should be named. I think that might be a vital part of the answer.

Comment: I'm thinking of the maintenance programmer that sees class="X" and wants to know where X is used.  He can search for .X in the css files, and also in the js files now that I think about it, but he would also have to search for 'X' and "X".

Comment: @Bryce. True.  I was showing how my development affects the class creation in both CSS and JS and how both end up with the same classes nearly all the time, therefore no special distinction.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn. I think the maintenance programmer will dive into either the js or the CSS depending on what he/she is updating/revising.  Sometimes you will need to go into both.

Comment: @Jason. Yea, I kind of figured that. So do you try to use camelcase for everything then? Or underscores?

Comment: @Bryce. When I first started developing with HTML & CSS only, I used underscores for everything.  However, once I started programming with js, I went with camelCase and stuck with it.  I prefer it now. You?

Comment: @Jason. It's mostly dependent on the data type I'm naming. In css, I tend to use hyphens. In just about any other language I'll use camelcase for classes, functions or other structures and lowercase and underscores for local variables like ints and strings. Also, it sometime depends on the project. Not sure if you've ever used Django before, but I'll name the view functions in camelcase and all other functions with underscores. So... for me it just depends on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

No real naming convention.

Sometimes (**most of the time**) I use classes **both** for css and for js.

Comment: agreed, as long as you pick one naming convention and **stick to it** your good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I try to name my classes based on the element they're describing as opposed to how they will be used.  If I have a bunch of `.definition` elements on my page, it doesn't matter whether I will make them green or if I want to have jquery loop over them, it's still a definition.