# When should I name things with initial capital letters?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

I have always wondered *when* to use identifiers (for example, functions) with capital first letter instead of camel case. I always write my JS in camel case like this:

```
function doStuff() {}

var simpleVar = 'some stuff',
    myAry = [],
    myObj = {};
```

... But I know I am supposed to name some things with capital first letters. I just don't know WHEN this rule applies. Hope somebody can make things a bit clearer to me.

Comment: Also of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions and http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the book "Javascript: the good parts", you should only capitalise the first character of the name of a function when you need to construct the object by "new" keyword.

This is called "the Constructor Invocation Pattern", a way to inherits.

Comment: A good argument against this is the fact that the BigInt constructor built into the language doesn't work with `new`, it throws an error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365203/why-is-bigint-not-a-constructor-function-unlike-number-boolean-and-string

EDIT: on second read, their reasoning is that it produces a primitive instead of an object, and `new Number` is an antipattern you shouldn't ever use

Answer (score 19):

The convention is to name [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) (i.e. functions that will be used with the `new` keyword) with starting capital.

```
function MyType(simpleVar) {
    this.simpleVar = simpleVar;
}

myObject = new MyType(42);
```

Comment: What about variables that happen to start with a capital letter, because they refer to an acronym - should the first letter, or the entire acronym be lowercased? Example: `ECBhandle` vs. `ecbHandle` (it does _not_ matter what ECB means).

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Personally, I treat acronyms the same as regular words, so in this case I would opt for `ecbHandle`. Other examples would be `parseXml` or `isbn`. This applies to constructor functions as well: e.g. `XmlParser`.

Comment: I like constants to be marked as ALLCAPS. Seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

The name convention states that class names are named with a first capital letter, I'm not sure how it's like with javascript, which is a prototype based language, but basically it's

```
class ClassName
var varName
function funcName()
```