# Can I use Capital letter for in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can i write something like this

```
class Person{
   testMethod(){

    return true;
   }
}

 var People = new Person();
 console.log(People.testMethod());
```

can i initialize with Capital Letter for class instance ?

Comment: Why not? (7 more characters to go)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I name things with initial capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687223/when-should-i-name-things-with-initial-capital-letters)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! But the standard in Javascript is that capital letter are for Classes or constructor functions! And camel case for variables and functions!

I really recommend you to use ESlint to force you to follow some code style! Also I recommend Standard JS rules: https://standardjs.com/ (probably the most used code style)

Comment: "The standard" is whatever you and your team choose. For me personally, I don't use classes and never need to capitalise any constructors.

Comment: It's true, but if everyone follows the same/similar standard, it makes it easier for people to read your code and third party code :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But it is not a standard way of naming your instance variables as it makes readability poor. If a third person reads your code, he/she would like to expect the Class names starting with Capital letters and instance variables with small letters.

Here is a list of naming conventions that should be followed as a good practice. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Coding_Style

Answer (score 0):

[Class name conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-class-names)

Class, interface, record, and typedef names are written in UpperCamelCase. Unexported classes are simply locals: they are not marked @private and therefore are not named with a trailing underscore.

Type names are typically nouns or noun phrases. For example, Request, ImmutableList, or VisibilityMode. Additionally, interface names may sometimes be adjectives or adjective phrases instead (for example, Readable).

[Rules common to all identifiers](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-rules-common-to-all-identifiers) -

Identifiers use only ASCII letters and digits, and, in a small number of cases noted below, underscores and very rarely (when required by frameworks like Angular) dollar signs.

Give as descriptive a name as possible, within reason. Do not worry about saving horizontal space as it is far more important to make your code immediately understandable by a new reader. Do not use abbreviations that are ambiguous or unfamiliar to readers outside your project, and do not abbreviate by deleting letters within a word.

```
priceCountReader      // No abbreviation.
numErrors             // "num" is a widespread convention.
numDnsConnections     // Most people know what "DNS" stands for.

n                     // Meaningless.
nErr                  // Ambiguous abbreviation.
nCompConns            // Ambiguous abbreviation.
wgcConnections        // Only your group knows what this stands for.
pcReader              // Lots of things can be abbreviated "pc".
cstmrId               // Deletes internal letters.
kSecondsPerDay        // Do not use Hungarian notation.
```

Comment: The Hungarian notation can out of nowhere for me. What’s the context?

Comment: read https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-rules-common-to-all-identifiers

Comment: I see that’s where you got your answer, but it doesn’t explain why they chose Hungarian. Maybe it was just an arbitrary example.

Comment: they said in general it's bad name for any identifier.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The sentiment is against [Systems Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian).

Comment: Thanks @TomBlodget