# Why is BigInt not a constructor function, unlike Number, Boolean and String?

Tags: javascript

[`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) and [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are constructor functions that correspond to those primitive types.

[`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is a function that corresponds to the BigInt primitive type, but it is not a constructor function.

```js
new BigInt(1n) // Uncaught TypeError: BigInt is not a constructor
```

Why?

Comment: This should help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: Also might as well ask why Symbol is like this as well 

Comment: For a similar reason like i.e: `const mr = new Math.round(23)` will produce the same error. Specifically it's a wrapper object. Not a constructor that can be instantiated.

Comment: The functions `Number`, `Boolean` and `String` can be used to create wrapper objects for those primitive types. `BigInt` is not a constructor (AFAICT), and therefore differs.

Comment: Well BigInt ( and this isn't just in JavaScript ) is treated LIKE a number .. But because it can have nth length it is a wrapper ..  This is why you can't use BigInt with arithmatic functions straight "out of the box" -- You have to manipulate it to do so ..

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - True -- but `Number` is a constructor, and returns an object. Same for `Boolean` and `String`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true that

Comment: @Zak "This is why you can't use `BigInt` with arithmetic functions straight 'out of the box'". You can use `BigInt` with arithmetic functions out of the box. `1n + 1n === 2n`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Ben --  Per the docs [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) -  *A BigInt value cannot be used with methods in the built-in Math object and cannot be mixed with a Number value in operations;*  --  It's not suppose to be able to.  I read that as *cannot be mixed with a Number value in operations* -- What you did above would be doing just that.

Comment: @Zak. OK, I understand you now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions for new primitive types (`Symbol`, `BigInt`) don't get construction signatures because TC39 doesn't think they need them. On [this issue on the `BigInt` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/161#issuecomment-405155723), Jordan Harband (TC39 member and former editor of the specification) said:

> Just like `Symbol`, it doesn't make sense to use `new` with things that produce a primitive. Since `BigInt` (like `Symbol`) is a primitive, it should only be invoked as a function.
>
> Pre-ES6 primitive constructors unfortunately must retain their `new`-ability, for back compat.

and from [this one](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/13) (also Jordan):

> ...users should never use `new` with a `Number` object tho, because it's widely considered a very bad practice to ever use boxed primitives.
>
> The new paradigm (no pun intended) is the one `Symbol` follows - if you want an object, you have to explicitly pass the primitive into `Object`. `new Primitive()` is a footgun, and new primitives should not continue this legacy pattern.

The use cases for `new String`, etc., are **very** few and far between (if there even are any that aren't better solved in other ways). Having construction signatures for `Number` and `String` and `Boolean` is confusing (do you create a string just by using a literal, or by using `new String`? why is it `new String("x") === "x"` is false? etc.). It looks like the committee decided to avoid that kind of confusion with newer primitives. (They still have object counterparts, it's just slightly less obvious how you get them, making it less likely to cause confusion.)

Comment: Thank you. What is a use case for the wrapper-object capability of `Number`, `Boolean` and `String`?

Comment: @BenAston - The closest thing I've seen to a use case is wanting to store additional information as a property on the object. For instance: `const amount = new Number(42); amount.currency = "USD";`. And to me, that's a **really** poor choice over (say) `const amount = {value: 42, currency: "USD"};` So... Dunno, maybe there aren't really any? :-)

Comment: Random thought: maybe compatibility with Java? Primitive numbers in Java are not reference types, but Java has a boxing capability. Maybe it was thought necessary to have an analogue.

Comment: @BenAston - Honestly, I think it was just a bad idea early on, perhaps brought on in part by the way primitives get methods from a prototype (which is by conceptually converting them to the equivalent object type). Remember how quickly JavaScript was thrown together initially. :-) If you really want to know, ping Brendan Eich on Twitter. He has a reasonable track record of answering questions like that. Or if you look around, you may find some statement he's previously made about it.

Comment: BTW: MDN claims that `BigInt` is a ["primitive wrapper object"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), which is thus incorrect?

Comment: @Ben no.  It is a primitive wrapper object .. Not a primitive ..  There is a difference..  Read [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript)

Comment: My bad: `BigInt` is still a primitive wrapper object. It's just that boxing can only be performed via auto-boxing, and not explicitly using a constructor (unlike Number, String, and Boolean).