# Javascript onclick="myfunction()" not working anymore

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have done this before but now I'm using the same technique on a new website I'm making but it doesn't work anymore. I went to the other website I've done before and the javascript button still works there. So it could be that I am doing something wrong with this code, but everything looks perfect! When I click the button Submit Globe which should call the function SubmitGlobe() and pops out a message box but it doesn't. This structure again works on my other website.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Favicon.png">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(251, 255, 221);" alink="#000099" link="#000099" vlink="#990099">

<div align="Center">

</div>
<br>

<input onclick="SubmitGlobe()" type="button" value="Submit Globe">

<script type="text/javascript">
Function SubmitGlobe()
{
alert("I am an alert box!")
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its `function` not `Function`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: Already answers are given by fellow users, what makes your comment ?

Comment: @Jay: For `javascript` naming conventions go through with [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions)

Comment: @Mahesh.D - because for such a simple error (typo) it's probably best just to post a comment. An answer to a question like this isn't going to help others in the future.

Comment: @Joe: I'm agree with you but "Nisarg Patel" and other already given answer before "Yogesh Suthar" then what is the need of comment here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put f in lowercase

```
    function SubmitGlobe(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to put `<script>` into head. Some browsers require functions to be defined already before execution. Also, do not use `CamelCase` for declaring functionw. It is only suitable for defining objects (Classes)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitGlobe()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>  
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Favicon.png">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(251, 255, 221);" alink="#000099" link="#000099" vlink="#990099">

<div align="Center">

</div>
<br>

<input onclick="submitGlobe();" type="button" value="Submit Globe">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didnt put `;` after the onclick event function

Comment: @Gautam3164 I just put it. But in fact it does not matter. Just check yourself. Program will run fine.

Comment: @Gautam3164 Semicolon is not mandatory in JS.

Comment: @budwiser: It actually is.  Just happens that JS has rules about how to insert them automagically in many -- but not all -- cases.  The big difference being those cases where it can't.

Comment: @cHao: True, and from the coders point of view, they're not (in most cases) mandatory in JS.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
<input onclick="SubmitGlobe();" type="button" value="Submit Globe">
```

You have missed `;` after function and your function should be like

```
function SubmitGlobe() {
    //Do the stuff
}
```

Comment: semi-colons aren't actually needed for statements that are one line or at the end of a line.

Comment: Yes its not manidatory ,thats why I also told him to put the Function to function

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: SubmitGlobe is not defined

Because you're using Function instead of `function`.

Replace Function with `function`.

Answer (score 0):

use this it will work fine. just copy and paste this code where you have written this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitGlobe()
{
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>  
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Favicon.png">
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(251, 255, 221);" alink="#000099" link="#000099" vlink="#990099">

<div align="Center">

</div>
<br>

<input onclick="return submitGlobe()" type="button" value="Submit Globe">


</body>
</html>
```

here in onclick i have used "return submitGlobe()" which will return the same nane i.e. submitGlobe () written inside your script tag also your alert() should end with a semicolon.

Comment: Are you playing "spot the difference"? Don't just post code, *explain* your solution.