# What is the best way to reference "this" in a CoffeeScript class in a function within a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Hopefully the question makes sense, the best way to explain would be to show you an example. I am creating a class in CoffeeScript and often use @ to represent "this" in JS, however, what is the best way to use it in the example below? At the moment I am storing @ in a local variable for that method, I was wondering if there was a better way

```
class app

constructor: ->
    # store @ or "this" in a new local var
    $this = @

    # do some stuff

    # Do some sort of jQuery stuff
    $(document).jquerystuff(->
        # do something that references this
        $this.anotherMethod()
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't use `$this` as an alias for `this` in your CoffeeScript class**. [`$foo` is a common notation for saying "this variable refers to a jQuery object,"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5640011/139010) but an arbitrary CoffeeScript class is not a jQuery.

Use [`=>`, the fat arrow,](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) instead of `->` and you won't need to alias `@` at all.

```
$(document).jquerystuff(=>
    @anotherMethod()
);
```

Alternately, if you do need to access the original jQuery- (or whatever-) provided `this` in the callback, and you care to follow Airbnb's JavaScript style guide, [the naming conventions dictate that you use `_this`](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming-conventions) as the alias:

```
_this = @

$(document).jquerystuff(->
    _this.anotherMethod()
);
```