# Javascript Naming Convention: value() vs getValue()

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

Imagine a simple object:

```
function createObj(someValue) {
    return {
        someFunction: function () {
            return someValue;
        }
    };
};
```

It basically does:

```
var obj = createObj("something");
var result = obj.someFunction(); // "something"
```

Now, `someFunction` refers to a function that returns a value.
What should be the correct naming convention used in javascript for the `someFunction` function?
Should it be named as what it does? Or its ok to name it with the name of the object that it returns?

I mean, should I name it `value()`, or should I name it `getValue()`? Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel that you are asking an opinion based question, which means it should be flagged and closed, BUT as a note:  Either follow company conventions or a format that you easily understand.  `getValue` is easy enough, unless you want to overload `value` such that it will get if there is not an arg to set...

Comment: getValue() is a poor name because it doesn't describe what the function does since almost every function gets a value. it should be something more like getBalance() or getUser()

Comment: the name **value** was just for example, of course I wouldn´t use that name for every function. If it returns a cow, it could be `cow()` or `getCow()`

Comment: Once again the meta-trolls, driven by the gamification of Q&A on SO have shut down a perfectly good question.  Of course there is "opinion".  There are excellent, valid reasons why I want to read the answers to a question like this. Most importantly, to find out what people consider "best practices".  One's code can be vastly improved based on such wisdom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "correct" naming in JavaScript. However, there are three conventions that are mostly used:

### Independent getter and setter:

In this approach, we create both a getter and a setter functions, like in Java:

```
var value;

this.getValue = function () {
    return value;
}

this.setValue(val) {
    value = val;
}
```

### Combined getter/setter method

In this approach, you have a single method that does both. The magic here is that it checks whether you provides a new value for your property:

```
var _value;

this.value = function (val) {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        // Acts like a setter
        _value = value;
        return this;
    }
    return _value;
}
```

It's also common to define your setter to return the actual instance of your class, so you can do this:

```
myObj
     .setProp1("foo")
     .setProp2("bar");
```

### Object.defineProperty

This one is less used, but it's also an option. It's similar to Objective-C `@property` statement:

```
var _value;
Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {
    get: function() {
        return _value;
    },
    set: function(val) { 
        _value = val;
    }
});
```

Then you can access it like if it was a public property:

```
console.log(myObj.value);  // Calls the getter method
myObj.value = newValue;    // Calls the setter method
```

Answer (score 1):

General naming conventions say `getValue()` would be the name of a function, where `value` would be the name of the variable.

So, if you were accessing the data directly, you would use `obj.value`, whereas if you were using a function to get some data, you would use `obj.getValue()`.

Comment: There's plenty of production JavaScript code out there, including code in many libraries, that strongly disagrees (see jQuery for example). Doesn't mean it's *right*, but this is really a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few naming conventions out there for Javascript in particular.

This question has a sister and hopefully this will help with your question: [Clicky for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

I am personally a fan of getValue and setValue but when reading other peoples codebase, i have seen

```
object.value = function(item){
  if (!item) return this.value;
  this.value = item;
}
```

jQuery uses this on the regular, which is why i don't want to necessarily bash on it.