# How to name a variable holding boundingClientRect of element?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, getboundingclientrect

How to name a variable holding result of `getBoundingClientRect()` function for given element. Now I'm always using names like `sendButtonBoundingClientRect` or `changeFontPanelBoundingClientRect` but with that naming convention names are very long. How do you guys naming it in your projects?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the following guides:

[Naming conventions in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions)

[JavaScript Style Guides And Beautifiers](http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is rather specific case :-)

Comment: There is no specific case, just name it so it would be understandable and meaningful for you and for the next person who will maintain your code (it could be you after 6 month)