# is this a good variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, naming

This seems fine to me but I wanted to know if it is ok to have two capital letters in a roll ("AF" in the case below).

```
let isScoreAFloat = score % 1 !== 0;
```

If this name is not the best, what name would better convey the possible result of the operation?

Thanks.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921133/javascript-naming-conventions

Comment: Perhaps if you are really just validating the number, `isScoreValid`.

Comment: you do not need to follow the grammar, `isScoreFloat` sounds good to me.

Comment: Well, as another developer I can clearly understand that this variable meaning is `there is a score and is it a float?`. then yea it does the job...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All JS numbers are 64 bit floats. I would use `!Number.isInteger(score)`, which is self explanatory.

Comment: If you were talking about a method, I'd use `isScoreAFloat`. As a result, I'd use `scoreIsAFloat` or just `scoreIsFloat`, because IMO it reads better as a condition. `if (scoreIsAFloat) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that variable name, it clearly explains what it holds.  Clarity is the most important thing in naming.  The variable name is not ambiguous!  If you're asking if the name is valid camel case, the answer to this is also yes.